# Prevent print dialog from refreshing page

Tags: php, javascript

I have an invoice which I have set up a print button for:

```
</script>
<!--Function for printing invoice-->
<script>
function printpage()
  {
  window.print()
  }
</script>

<button id="print" name="print" class="btn btn-info"onClick="printpage()">Print Invoice</button>
```

Now on clicking the button, the print dialog appears as expected, however, if I cancel the print option, the invoice page refreshes and all the information is lost.Is there a way that I can cancel the print dialog but not have the page refreshed?

I suspect I need to reference the click event of the dialog box, but this is where I run into difficulty.
Thank's

Just for anyone looking in the future, the button HTML was amended to:

```
<button id="print" name="print" type="button"class="btn btn-info"onClick="printpage()">Print Invoice</button>
```

This stops the print dialog box when canceled, from refreshing the page and thus from losing any info that was dynamically produced/pulled in from a DB.

Comment: Sounds heavily browser-dependent to me. Is this Internet Explorer by any chance? Most sites open a new tab with the information formatted for printing, and I suppose since it's static content it doesn't matter if it refreshes.

Comment: Cheers Dave, I should have mentioned that the content is read in from a DB, as too are the header and footer content.@Quentin solved the issue. Again, thank's.  Dave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried reproducing your problem, but the only way I could do so was to put the button in a form.

Say `type="button"` to stop it being a submit button that submits the form.

Comment: Quentin, first off, Thank you very much.Your hint was spot on, I do feel a bit of an idiot for not spotting this myself.  Dave

Answer (score 3):

Try to return false from the onclick handler:

```
onClick="printpage(); return false"
```